# Animated arrow pointer

Tags: jquery

I have been looking for a way to create an animated arrow which points to a div element on a webpage with little success.

The reason is I need to draw the users attention to a particular div.

I am using jQuery if that helps. I found PointPoint but it only has an arrow on the edge of the mouse.

Comment: The work is currently much in progress, but you can look at [Yarrow](http://krispo.github.io/yarrow/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For animated cursor, you must have an `.ani` file (animated cursor) which you want to use.

HTML example:

```
<div class="item1">abcdefgh</div>

<div class="item2">asdasdasdasdas</div>
```

CSS Example

```
.cursor1 { cursor: help;}

.item1 { line-height: 20px;
         border: 1px solid #000;
          height: 100px;   
          width: 100px;               
}
```

For custom cursor read here: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/  to use in above CSS.

and JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item1").on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("cursor1");       
    });        
});
```

My answer is that I understood from your query.